# Visual Studio SSIS Package throws error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, ssis-2014

I have been working on a SSIS package. Package is extracting data from Access Databases , excel sheets and SQL server databases and loading into SQL Server database.

Its been working fine but all of a sudden it has started throwing an error, Its not a run-time error, but whenever I open the solution in Visual Studio, the takes a couple of minutes to validate all the package components (which is expected because the package is huge) at the end of the validation it throws the following error:

[image]

I have searched online and it appears that some other people has also encountered the same issue but no one seems to have suggested a proven method to fix it.

I have tried registering the dts.dll because some of the posts online suggested this should fix the issue but no joy.

Any pointers or suggestion in the right direction are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Two things I can think of: You could try splitting your package into smaller packages or you could try turning off validation.

Comment: And you said this error only occurs when validating, not when running the package?

Comment: Whenever I open the package it takes about 2 minutes for validation to complete and towards the end it throws this error. The same package works fine on another machine. I have uninstalled and installed the visual studio on that machine, I uninstalled and then installed the ssdt but still no joy.